# Spring select tag generating hidden field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not very familiar with the Spring tag and seems like i am struck in some issue which i am not able to understand as of now.

I have displaying two select tags in my jsp and they are backed by an Arraylist and map here is the code for them

```
<form:select path="prsBTOData[${status.index}].colors" items="${prsBTOData.colors}" 
cssClass="productDetailsSelect"/>
```

and

```
<form:select path="prsBTOData[${status.index}].fonts" items="${prsBTOData.fonts}" 
cssClass="productDetailsSelect" >
```

colors is being backed by Array list while the fonts is being backed by the Map.below is the generated HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="productDetailsSelect" name="prsBTOData[0].colors" 
    id="prsBTOData0.colors">
     <option selected="selected" value="Red">Red</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="Green">Green</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="Black">Black</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="_prsBTOData[0].colors">
```

i am not sure why its doing `multiple="multiple"` and not showing any drop down but only showing the `RED` as selected value, while i was expecting a list with drop down options.
even not sure why this hidden field is getting generated and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

In `form:select` the `items` attribute is the list of items that needs to be displayed in select box. And `path` attribute is the property that is bound with the selected value.

As you have given an arraylist (having multiple values) as the path, spring assumed you wanted a multiple value selected drop down.

You might want to give like this (assuming you have `color` property for `prsBTOData` )

```
<form:select path="prsBTOData.color" items="${prsBTOData.colors}"/>
```

And consider using separate model objects for maintaining static/reference data (colors,fonts) as below:

```
<form:select path="prsBTOData.color" items="${referenceData.colors}"/>
```