# Spring form:select JSP tag always uses multiple

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a spring webapp using form:select tag. The tag is as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${info.formAreas}" var="area">
    <div class="area">
    <form:label path="areas">${area.name}</form:label>
    <form:select id="form_area_${area.id}" items="${area.options}" path="areas" class="area_select"/>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Where `areas` is a `String[]` on my form-bound object, and `${info.formAreas}` is a List of `AreaDTO`, reproduced below:

```
public class AreaDTO {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String shortName;
  private boolean dontmind;

  public Map<String,String> getOptions() {
    Map<String,String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    options.put(id+":0", "No");
    if (dontmind) options.put(id+":1", "Don't Mind");
    options.put(id+":2", "Yes");
    return options;
  }

  //other getters/setters
}
```

The resulting HTML if as follows:

```
<div class="area">
    <label for="areas">An Area Name</label>
    <select id="form_area_1" name="areas" class="area_select" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1:0" selected="selected">No</option>
      <option value="1:1">Don&#39;t Mind</option>
      <option value="1:2">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="_areas" value="1"/>
 </div>
```

Firstly, why is it producing `multiple="multiple"`, I only want a single-select dropdown, and secondly, where is the hidden input coming from?

Comment: Seems like the same question as this one (no answers with votes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483849/spring-select-tag-generating-hidden-field

Comment: So judging from the comment above, if your `areas` variable is something that holds multiple values (a `List`, for instance), then you will get a multiselect.

Comment: @Tobb yes - that was it!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you get a single- or multi-select depends on the type of the variable used to hold what is selected (the `path`-variable). If this is a collection of some sorts (e.g. a `List`) it will become a multi-select.

The hidden input field is probably just something `Spring` uses internally, perhaps for posting some value when nothing is selected.